# Find the angles of a triangle given the area

Tags: trigonometry

For a triangle $ABC$ if:

The area = $\frac{(a+b)^2}{8}$

Find its angles .

**My attempt:**

$\frac{1}{2} a b \sin{C} = \frac{(a+b)^2}{8}$

$2ab(2\sin{C} -1) = a^2 + b^2 $

$2\sin{C} -1 = \frac{a^2 +b^2}{2ab}$

$2\sin{C} -1$ =$ \frac{a^2 + b^2 -c^2}{2ab} + \frac{c^2}{2ab}$

= $\cos{C} +  \frac{c^2}{2ab}$

But i could not go on any more i need a hint ?

Comment: If you let $a=b=1$, then you can find side $c$ using Heron's formula, which makes a well-defined triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. I have edited out some calculation mistakes including the missing $2$ in front of the $\sin C$. I think it's this mistake that makes the progress hard.

Notice the following inequality:
$$2\sin{C} -1 = \frac{a^2 +b^2}{2ab} \geq1 \implies \sin C \geq 1$$

We can immediately infer that $C$ is $90$ degrees and $a^2+b^2=2ab$ which implies the other two angles  are both $45$ degrees.